# what is the purpose of using this parameter, int (*cmp) (void*, void*)

Tags: c, parameters, int, void, void-pointers

in my homework ı couldn't understand this parameter ;

```
set_maker(LINKEDSTACK stack, int (*cmp) (void*, void*))
```

can anybody explain this using?

thank you for helping.

Comment: It's a comparison function that the caller supplies, which is used to compare a new value with what's already in the stack.

Comment: This allows the stack to hold data of any type, because the caller supplies the comparison function.

Comment: Shouldn't it be referred as `set`, not `stack`? Or it is a stack where you can remove duplicate elements?

Comment: LINKEDSTACK set_maker is the correct one, how can ı use this parameter in function , should ı write a function for comparison?

Comment: @MertSezigen Check this for usage example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm

Answer (score 2):

It is a pointer to a function taking two pointer arguments and returning an `int`.  Judging from its name, the semantics of the function are that it compares the two objects pointed to and returns a value <0, 0 or >0 indicating the relative *order* of the two object according to some ordering criteria.

The purpose of such a parameter is to allow the function (`set_maker()` in this case) to operate on objects of arbitrary type and ordering rules.  For example if you were operating in `int` objects, you might have a function:

```
int icompare(const void * a, const void * b) 
{
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

Then you could call `set_maker()` thus:

```
set_maker( istack, icompare ) ;
```

so that `set_maker()` can operate on a `LINKEDSTACK` of `int`s. (I'm making a somewhat reasoned guess here since you have provided no details of `set_maker()` or `LINKEDSTACK`).

Equally the comparison function could operate on `struct` objects with more complex comparison rules involving multiple members.  So its purpose is to make `set_maker()` flexible enough to handle any data type without duplicating a great deal of code by providing the rules for handling each data type in the provided function.

A standard library example of such a function is [qsort()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/), although you will notice there that the parameters are of type `const void*` which is best practice for functions that are not intended to *modify* the objects referenced.

Comment: I would think this function is rather for equality testing as it is passed to function to make a set (remove duplicates)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Most likely, but it is normal semantics for a compare to indicate _order_.  The calling function may indeed test only for zero/non-zero.  I was trying to keep it generic since we can only guess at what the function does.

Answer (score 0):

`int (*cmp) (void*, void*)`

It is the pointer to the function taking two parameters of type `void *` and returning `int`

It should be probably the function which compares two pointers or objects referenced by the pointers - who knows

Comment: Compares two objects to which the pointers refer, rather then comparing the pointers themselves.  I am sure that is what you meant but it is perhaps not clear.

Comment: True, but unlikely.  If all you were to do was compare pointers, you would pass the pointers directly rather than a function-pointer.  There are not many ways you can compare one pointer with another (one).

Comment: @Clifford because I do not know I have amended my answer to cover both options. Interesting who and why DV-ted my answer

Comment: I see that, and all good as far as I am concerned. It takes a great deal for me to exercise a down vote - offensiveness or spam generally, never a valid attempt to help regardless of quality or effectiveness, and certainly not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In C such functions like bsearch and qsort that deal with ordered sequences need a function that will compare elements of arrays.

A pointer to such a function is declared like

```
int ( *cmp )( const void *, const void * )
```

It accepts as arguments pointers to two objects that will be compared. Within the function the pointers after casting to the required type are dereferenced and the pointed objects are compared.

The function shall return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first pointed object is considered, respectively, to be less than, to match, or to be greater than the second pointed object.

It seems that the function `set_maker` uses within its body such a comparison function to make comparison between two objects for example for ordering them.

.